how to filter lists by content type using Rest API on SharePoint Subscription Edition?
Is there a way to retrieve lists filtered by content type?
The rest api below does not work:
/_api/Web/lists?$select=ContentTypes/Name&$expand=ContentTypes&$filter=ContentType eq 'Message'

SharePoint Subscription Edition

I don't think it's possible. The only other option is to get all the content types per list (using guid) and then apply filter on the summarized results.
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/contenttypes


See more info here
Also, this might help
